# How can I indentify the source of countless server requests being made from Visual Studio to our company server?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am using VS2019 and work with a vpn that connects me to an internal company server. For some reason that absolutely escapes me (and IT support), 100s of server requests are being made from VS to that server whenever I open a particular project.

It is trying to use my machine name / username to gain access to something on the server side.

I have combed through all the project solution files and dependencies. Nothing that I can find is pointing anywhere other than local.

My question is:

what could be the cause of this?
Is there a way to debug/step through the initialisation of VS when it opens that project?
is there a way to view a log of remote requests (and ideally their response status) being by VS as they occur?

Comment: Maybe this is caused by Source Control, if source control is not required you could try disabling it and see if it resolves the issue: Goto Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plugin-Selection, Change the Current source control plugin to "None" Save settings and reopen the project.